# Yammer авторизация в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, oauth2

Нужно из консольного приложения получить токен для авторизации. Насколько описано в документации сначала нужно отправить GET запрос по URL

```
https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[:client_id]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[:redirect_uri]
```

После чего из полученного HTML из ответа получаем authenticity_token, после чего делаем POST запрос

```
https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token
client_id=[:client_id]&client_secret=[:client_secret]&code=[:code]&grant_type=authorization_code
```

из которого получаем наш Token. Проблема в том, что второй URL возвращает ошибку 404. Вот мой код для POST метода. Кто-нибудь объяснит, что я делаю не так?

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_tokenclient_id=8hSj5TCwX0SSOY2i2v8oxQ&client_secret=SvWaLSSjSkwfZN8zNi65EMLKhXbl7AdX14ny8LH6Cw&code=pLhXqAi6BvFENHM0hwU1bSmpQDwpUyvc/Mn+bhXlKAA=&grant_type=authorization_code");
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = data.Length;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
```

При выполнении получаю 404 Not Found.

Документация тут
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/oauth-2